# Линукс для ноутбука

Tags: ноутбук, linux

Здравствуйте.

Есть ноутбук 5ти летней давности выпуска. Модель - Asus A6Jc. 2 ядра, 2 гига, винт IDE на 100 гигов, видео nVidia встроенная.

Давно есть желание установить на него Линукс. Пробовал Убунту - тормозит (пробовал потому, что на слуху). Пробовал Сусе - не совсем качественно работает, иногда виснет (выбрал потому, что вроде бы как лучше всего заточено под ноутбуки). И в первом и втором варианте графика подтормаживает даже при обычном офисном режиме работы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может, есть какие-то еще дистрибутивы Линукса для ноута такой конфигурации? Windows XP просто летает. А вот свободное ПО работать нормально отказывается..=(

Заранее, Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коммерческий драйвер на видео не пробовали ставить?

Comment: простите, Уважаемый, а что значит "коммерческий"? =) от производителя?

Comment: они самые !

Comment: =) спасибо! буду пробовать. =)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй **linux mint** с lxde у меня на нетбуке ничего не тормозит, так там у меня intel атом и гиг оперативки, хотя мне кажется и ubunta с lxde нормально должна работать

Comment: с lxde да, согласен, работает хорошо. не спорю. =) но..как бы это сказать, чтоб тухлыми помидорами не забросали...=))) типа красивостей хочется. =) хоть и на Форточках ставлю минимальные красивости и весь рабочий стол в классику перевожу..Вот попробую с дровами на видюшку от производителя, тогда видно будет. Может, так и перейду на lxde. =)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй какой-либо из лёгких дистрибутивов. Советую PuppyRus, добротный русифицированный и сообщество доброжелательное :)

Comment: да, я согласен, что и лёгкий, и симпатичный, работает шустро, собран добротно. пробовал, понравился очень. но. =) установка на винт мне не понравилась. многие вещи приходится догадываться как сделать. на форуме задавать вопросы стесняюсь...=))) привык сам докумекивать. но сейчас что-то пилить самому не хочется совершенно. =) хочется поставить и забыть. =)

Answer (score 0):

если хрюша летает, то убунта тормозить не должна. дело в графике. попробуй lxde - баланс между функциональностью и лёгкостью, хотя я использую fluxbox

Comment: буду пробовать драйвера от производителя ставить. а если так и будет тупить, придётся Puppy-ком пользоваться... =)

Answer (score 0):

У меня на Acer Aspire 3680 (года 2004 выпуска) прекрасно себя чувствует [xUbuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) — дистрибутив Убунты для маломощных машин.

Comment: ок. =) Спасибо. А вот об этом я не слышал. =) С удовольствием попробую. =)Правда, я смотрю, у них 2 вида дистрибутивов: alternate и desktop. Какой более предпочтителен?

Comment: Alternative — это возможность а-ля LiveCD с последующей установкой, Desktop — установка из под BIOS в текстовом режиме.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно википедии «Основное отличие Xubuntu от базового варианта — среда рабочего стола Xfce. Большинство прикладного ПО также взято из этой среды.»а вы ведь хотели бы не использовать простую рабочую среду (lxde). Может, конечно, Xfce будет лучше, чем lxde. А так — вы по сути уже и так сделали себе xubuntu, если ставили lxde.. ну, точнее, «lubuntu» какую-нибудь;)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте knoppix. Можете поработь как с лив-сд версией, а потом уже установить. На вашей конфигурации проблем не будет.

Comment: Knoppix пробовал когда-то, лет 10 назад. =) но как мне показалось, это чисто сидишный Линукс для аварийного использования. Я таким образом использую PuppyRus. =)Сейчас пробую xUbuntu. =)

Answer (score 0):

hp compaq 6720s dual core. 1 гиг оперативки, встроенная intel. Ubuntu 11.10 нормально работает Unity. Притормаживает при копированнии, а так все на ура, сёрфить по нету супер, кино смотреть и в консоли работать тож ресурсов много не надо. Даж умудряюсь виртуалку запускать с xp для некоторых нужд. У Вас помощьнее будет ноут, lxde fsce ставил тож думал быстрее будет, но нет..... На крайний случай gnome-fallback-session.

Comment: =) спасибо, Уважаемый. буду пробовать. =) xUbuntu 11.10 работает нормально, довольно шустро. но, как я понял, допиливать всё равно придётся разные мелочи...драйвера под видео однозначно буду с офф.сайта ставить.